# HTTPD as File Owner

Tags: php, apache

I created a temporary file using fopen in php and get the file owner/user id and username. My question is

Is it always httpd a username for php generated file?
Is it always for apache? Can we change the username for apache?

Answer (score 3):

You can view/change the user that Apache runs as with [the `User` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#user). (Directives are found in the `httpd.conf` file, usually in /etc/apache2, on a Mac.) If you want PHP and Apache to run as different users, then you can use the Suexec module to switch to a different user when running PHP scripts.

- [Suexec module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#suexec)
- [Suexec UserGroup directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_suexec.html)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712878/apache-itk-vs-suexec/) for a discussion of the pros and cons of Suexec vs MPM-ITK.